# Configure doorkeeper's resource_owner_authenticator without other gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, restful-authentication, doorkeeper

I'm currently adding a RESTful API on to the sample app from the Rails Tutorial, and I'm trying to secure it using doorkeeper without other gems like devise or clearance. I want doorkeeper to authenticate a user based on an existing session. The current sessions implementation keeps a `remember_token` in the browser cookies (assigned at signin) and stores the hashed token in the User model.

I have a `current_user` method in the `SessionsHelper` module (app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb), which is also included in the ApplicationController:

```
def current_user
  remember_token = User.digest(cookies[:remember_token])
  @current_user ||= User.find_by(remember_token: remember_token)
end
```

Here is `resource_owner_authenticator` (other failed implementations are commented out):

```
resource_owner_authenticator do
  # fail "Please configure doorkeeper resource_owner_authenticator block located in #{__FILE__}"
  # Put your resource owner authentication logic here.
  # Example implementation:
  #   User.find_by_id(session[:user_id]) || redirect_to(new_user_session_url)
  # puts current_user || "no user"
  # current_user # || redirect_to(signin_path)
  # remember_token = User.digest(request.cookies[:remember_token])
  # User.find_by(remember_token: remember_token)
  # puts "in resource_owner_authenticator"
  current_user
end
```

Here's the error from one GET request:

```
Started GET "/users/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-24 12:40:25 -0400
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
Filter chain halted as #<Proc:0x007f294c886310@/home/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/doorkeeper-1.4.0/lib/doorkeeper/helpers/filter.rb:8> rendered or redirected
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

I'm wondering, first of all, whether it's possible to authenticate without devise or clearance, and even if it is, whether it's advisable. Secondly, I'm not sure exactly what's available in `Doorkeeper.configure` -- is `current_user`? Are cookies? If anyone can see what I'm doing wrong here, thanks. I'm using Rails 4 and Doorkeeper 1.4.0.

Comment: Any luck with that so far?

Comment: I was able to solve this yesterday by changing the resource_owner_authenticator like this:

resource_owner_authenticator do 
  User.find_by_id(session[:user_id]) || warden_authenticate!(scope: :user)
end

I am using devise and rails 4.1.